# Web on mobile - Open URLs in full browser apps when navigating from Chrome Custom Tabs or Safari ViewController

Tags: android, ios, web, chrome-custom-tabs, sfsafariviewcontroller

I have a web page that is often launched from inside an Android/iOS app in their respective "tab system", Chrome Custom Tabs / SFSafariViewController.

The requirement I have is to have some urls redirect and open in the full browser app instead of navigating in the tab/controller.

I tried adding to one of those URLs the `href` `target="_blank" or use` window.open()` but in Android at least that opens a custom tab inside of the existing tab. Haven't had the chance to test that on iOS as of yet but I have the sneaking suspicion it will do nothing as the Safari View Controller does not support windows.

Any ideas on how I can force these 2 tools to open a url in the full apps would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people who might come across this and are interested.

Unfortunately it is not possible to force the in app browser to open a new tab in the full version of it. Like I mention in the question, iOS simply can't do that due to the nature of the `SFSafariViewController`, while in Android it does not work... for reasons I guess, could not find something concrete and I will not go into speculating the reasons.

The solution I ended up using on my side is:
Have the site send a deep link to the app with the URL that it should open externally, the app forces the in app browser to close and launches the received URL in the full browser.

I am setting this as the answer for now. If anyone comes with a better solution or an immediate solution to the problem, I am more than happy to change it.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Twitter and whatsapp open webpages in CCT and SVC, but FB messenger doesn't, because it opens in its in-app-browser (IAB), unless you change your phone settings.

But. I found this javascript which works for me, for safari on iphone and chrome on android. Put it in the beginning of your index page at the end of your header and refer to this same index page.
Of course change yourwebpagetoopenoutsidewbhere to your own page.

```
var standalone = window.navigator.standalone,
  userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),
  safari = /safari/.test(userAgent),
  ios = /iphone|ipod|ipad/.test(userAgent);

var qq;

if (ios) {
  if (!standalone && safari) {
    // Safari
  } else if (!standalone && !safari) {
    // iOS webview
       s=location.toString().split('?');s=s[1];
       qq="https://www.yourwebpagetoopenoutsidewbhere.com/index.php?" + s;
       window.close(); // Close the empty view window
       window.open(qq,'_system', 'location=yes', replace);
  }
} else {
  if (userAgent.includes('wv')) {
     // Android webview
       s=location.toString().split('?');s=s[1];
       qq="https://www.yourwebpagetoopenoutsidewbhere.com/index.php?" + s;
       window.close(); // Close the empty view window
       var winloc = 'intent:' + qq + '#Intent;end';
       window.location = winloc;

  } else {
    // Chrome
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure how that answers any part of my question. I am aware of settings and handling of links by the platform. What I wanted to know is if there is a way to force the platform to react to a web side action in the IAB, opening the external browser.